# Not understanding std::filesystem::directory_iterator

Tags: c++

I just started looking into C++ and have been reading a book and am only a couple of chapters in.

I thought a good exercise would be to print out a directory. When I look it up, I see this nice `for` loop that is driving the train [from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/).

```cpp
for (const auto & entry : fs::directory_iterator(path))
    std::cout << entry.path() << std::endl;
```

My next logical step was going to store these values in a vector or an array.

For the past three hours, I have not been able to figure it out. What is `entry`? Is it a constant? Is it a string? What's stopping me from placing it in a vector? I can't get this code to run.

I am sorry for the basic question, I just need some conceptual clarification.

This is my code, `push_back()` does not take constants and I can't convert the constants to a string. What am I missing?

```cpp
auto filepath()
{
    std::vector <string> lis;
    std::string path = "C:/Users/Derek Comeau/3D Objects";
    
    for (const auto& entry : filesystem::directory_iterator(path)) {
        const string paths = entry.path();
        lis.push_back(paths);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is your trail , https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator -> reference : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_entry path: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_entry/path string: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [Range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) iterates through a container using its iterators.  In this case, there is no container, `directory_iterator` acts stand-alone.

When the `directory_iterator` is constructed, it finds the first file in the specified folder.  When the loop dereferences the iterator via its [`operator*`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator/operator*), it returns a [`const directory_entry&`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_entry) to the current file.  When the loop advances the iterator via its [`operator++`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator/increment), it advances to the next file.  Repeating until there are no more files to report.

The [`directory_entry::path()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_entry/path) method returns a [`const path&`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path), not a `std::string`.  However, the [`path::string()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/string) method returns a `std::string`.

`std::vector` does not have a `pushback()` method.  The correct name is [`push_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back).

With that said, try this instead:

```cpp
auto filepath()
{
    vector<std::string> lis;
    std::string folder = "C:/Users/Derek Comeau/3D Objects";

    for (const auto& entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(folder)) {
        lis.push_back(entry.path().string());
    }

    return lis;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply ! Ok so directory_iterator returns an iterator that is stand alone and works well with a range based for loop. Is that a good way of thinking about it? Then within the for loop you can call the push_back method placing entry.path().string(), within a vector, which is an object that returns a string?

Comment: @umfan110 "*directory_iterator returns an iterator*" - no, it IS the iterator. "*and works well with a range based for loop*" - yes, because it implements [`std::begin()` and `std::end()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator/begin) overloaded functions for that exact purpose.

Comment: Thanks Remy for the clarification. I think I understand now.